# Partitioning Allocated Space on Drive

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, windows-xp

I want to partition a drive allocated with 65 GB into 10 GB and 55 GB. I've found a tool called 'Partition Magic' which is able to separate drives without formatting them.

Currently I have 20 GB free space on 65 GB. For a new drive to be allocated with 10 GB, Does it require the physical address space to be contiguous? Is it best to defragment the whole drive before partitioning?

Comment: Don't use that. Use gParted Live CD instead (it's free).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you do need the space to be contiguous and it's best to defragment before partitioning.